# Incomplete list into dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Here's a little list:

```
foo <- list(c("johnny", "joey"), character(0), "deedee")

[[1]]
[1] "johnny" "joey"  

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
[1] "deedee"
```

How can I transform it into this data frame?

```
  list_item   name
1         1 johnny
2         1   joey
3         3 deedee
```

All list-to-dataframe solutions I've seen don't work because my list in incomplete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `stack` from `base R` after setting the `names` of the 'foo' as the sequence of 'foo'.

```
stack(setNames(foo, seq_along(foo))) 
#    values ind
#1 johnny   1
#2   joey   1
#3 deedee   3
```

Answer (score 7):

The `melt` function of package `reshape2` works on lists, too. So you can use:

```
library(reshape2)
melt(foo)
#   value L1
#1 johnny  1
#2   joey  1
#3 deedee  3
```

I believe you know how to change the names afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way with base R:

```
data.frame(list_item=rep(seq_along(foo), sapply(foo, length)), 
           name=unlist(foo))


##   list_item   name
## 1         1 johnny
## 2         1   joey
## 3         3 deedee
```

---

As mentioned by @RichardScriven in comments, `sapply(foo, length)` can be replaced with `lengths(foo)`.

Answer (score 1):

`melt` is ultra cool (system.time 1.74 for a list of 10k) and @jbaums' `unlist` solution is just as fast when `lengths` is used (1.72), but @akrun's `stack` solution wins cause it's so ridiculously fast (0.06). As expected, the loop is slowest (21.86).

Answer (score 0):

This works with the given example:

```
foo <- list(c("johnny", "joey"), character(0), "deedee")

result=data.frame()
for(listitem.no in 1:length(foo)){
  for(vectoritem in foo[[listitem.no]])
    result <- rbind(result, c(listitem.no, as.character(vectoritem)),
                    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}
```

HTH,
Bernhard